# Q promise & synchronous I/O

Tags: javascript, sqlite, promise

After reading the Q documentation, I was under the impression that the following would wait on SELECT thereby providing a sync I/O capability. Assume db is an open SQLite database.

```
   count = 500;
   Q.invoke(db, 'get', "SELECT * FROM blah blah ...").done(
      function () { --count; },
      function () { // error code}
   );
   console.log(count);
```

Testing reveals that is not true. How can I get the SELECT and its result synchronized via the promise methodology so that the console output is 499?

I really want to wrap this in a while loop that processes X number of rows where any given row can decrease count by a value retrieved from that row. The number of times through the loop is data dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without introducing threads or fibers, it is not possible to make an asynchronous operation look like a synchronous operation.  As such, you will need to put your `console.log` inside the handler that notifies you when the operation has completed.

```
var count = 500;
Q.invoke(db, 'get', "SELECT * FROM blah blah ...")
.then(function (results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var result = results[i];
        --count;
    }
})
.done();
```

Some database API’s will permit you to stream your results. You will need to look for that in the documentation. Ideally it will look like:

```
var count = 500;
Q(db)
.invoke("getStream", "SELECT * FROM blah blah blah")
.invoke("forEach", function (result) {
    --count;
})
.then(function () {
    assert.equals(count, 0);
})
.done();
```

Comment: You've answered my question by stating categorically that Q won't create a sync capability, but things I hadn't heard of (threads/fibers) will. I'll check them out.

Answer (score 0):

Count will be decremented asynchronously, so you have to print it inside the successsfull `then` callback:

```
count = 500;
Q.invoke(db, 'get', "SELECT * FROM blah blah ...").then(
  function () { --count; console.log(count); },
  function () { // error code}
);
```

You cannot really put that into the loop, as promises won't make your code synchronous in any way. I think what you're really looking for is promises/generators combo:

```
Q.async(function* () {
  var count = 0;
  // Notice the regular loop here
  while (count > 0) {
    count -= yield Q.invoke(db, 'get', 'SELECT * FROM blah blah ...');
    console.log(count);
  }
});
```

Notice two new constructs here: `yield` keyword and `function*` declaration. Those are being worked on for ECMAScript 6.

If you're using Node.js, you can try them out today. Just run node with the harmony flag:

```
$ node --harmony --harmony-generators script.js
```

Comment: A bit too futuristic for me right now. I'm working on a Chrome app and have to stay within what it supports today. I also prefer to let new things age before I use them in production code. I'm new to JS and I'm still learning about its basic functionality. Haven't even gotten to popular libraries like JQuery yet. Thanks for the heads up on what's coming.